# Network errors with axios/fetch and react-native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

I have an react-native project set up and I've been able to test it using expo. Problem is that I am unable to successfully send requests with `axios` or `fetch`. After some searching here I apparently have to edit the `androidmanifest.xml` file to allow for requests to be sent with `http`. Problem is I don't have this file

I'm just using react-native and expo, I'm not emulating any app.

Code:

```
handleSubmit(event){
   const { email, password, password_confirmation } = this.state;
    const options = {
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    };
     console.log("HERE 1")
    axios
      .post("http://127.0.0.1:3001/",
      {
      user:{
      email: "public@healthinbound.ca"}
      },
      options,
      ).then(response => {
      console.log("RESPONSE", response)}).catch((err) => console.log("ERR", err))
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: what's at this address? http://127.0.0.1:3001/

Comment: Be sure you mean that IP and not the host machine's IP. You probably need to look up `adb reverse` in the react native docs.

Comment: @azium hey, that's where my api is being hosted

Comment: @zero298 I want to send to the IP where my API is running, which is the one you see there

Comment: @zero298 and thank you I will look that up

Comment: @CharlesSmith What @azium probably means is that, usually, `127.0.0.1` means "myself" from a device's perspective.  If the phone is asking "itself" for API data, it probably fails because the phone isn't hosting the data API, the computer you are coding on does.  You probably want to send the request to the **actual host IP** which is probably something like `192.168.0.10` (you'll need to get the actual IP of the computer).

Comment: @zero298 Ohhh, wow that sounds obvious now. Okay I'll give that a try, thank you so much

Comment: @zero298 I've gotten rid of the network error issue, thank you. However now it seems that nothing is happening when that axios function is supposed to run. No error, or sign on my api that it's received

Comment: Must still be a problem with the address because I tested it with a call to the google maps api and it worked

Comment: Never mind I figured it out, I was using the wrong IP address from the `ipconfig` command. If you want to submit your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it!